# pandas duplication removing nans

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, duplicates

I am trying to check for duplicates. 
I use `df['name_duplicated'] = df.duplicated('name', keep=False)`
However, this treats any row with `name` = `NaN` as a duplicate.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

I am trying `df[pd.isnull(df['name'])]['name_duplicated'] = False` but I get an error.

Comment: Why not drop them first? `df['name_duplicated'] = df['name'].dropna().duplicated()`?

Comment: @EdChum I don't want to drop them (yet) because I'm also filtering on another column. Only if this is False and another column is True will i want to drop them

Comment: Actually the default behaviour is that `NaN` produces `False` isn't this what you want? `df['name_duplicated'] = df[df['Name'].duplicated()]`?

Comment: that is what I want, but weird, for some reason my `NaN`s are producing `True`

Comment: Are they really `NaN` though? what does `df[df['Name'].isnull()]` show?

Comment: `df[df['name'].isnull()]` shows `NaN`s in the `Name` column. And when I export to excel there is nothing there

Comment: I can't comment about excel but the above code is correct

Comment: hmm ok thanks EdChum.. i'll keep looking into it i must have something wonky somewhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try also checking for NaNs and doing a boolean and operation on the results of the duplicated call

```
df['name_duplicated'] = df.duplicated('name', keep=False) & df['name'].notnull()
```

Comment: thank you! I didn't realize you could add in a boolean at the end like that